# Implement SQL Server on Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set (VMSS)

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-server

Can I build a SQL Server with always on availability group on Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set?

Comment: Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-overview?view=azuresql

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, but it would be tricky due to the nature of VMSS.

Comment: Is there a guide for that?

Comment: well, i doubt that

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-availability-group-prereq

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/quick-create-portal.

Comment: I know that guide, but it is not meant for VMSS